# Column Reorder in PBI - I Want to rearrange/sort the order of my data within the columns in my report

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop

I HAVE A REPORT WITH TWO COLUMN PARAMETERS - YEAR AND MEASURE. YEAR IS FIRST AND UNDER MEASURE THERE IS NST AND OIS.
HOWEVER CURRENTLY, IT IS SHOWING NST BEFORE OIS (BECAUSE OF ASCENDING ORDER, BUT I WANT OIS TO SHOW FIRST.
ANY WAY TO SORT THAT OR CHANGE THE ORDER.

ATTACHED IMAGE TO SHOW -
[EXAMPLE :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df9al.png)

I TRIED TO SORT, MOVE MEASURE ETC. NOTHING SEEMS TO BE HELPING

Comment: Can you add the dax for the measure(s) of OIS / NST? There are ways to custom sort columns.